# Flutter comment_tree 0.3.0 How to remove replies under comments

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I use the component as in the description, I can’t figure out how to remove the answer (child component) in the component itself, or at least how to check if it exists, then show it, if not, then don’t show it.

https://gist.github.com/lomanu4/3abba49f6fbcecbde4c07df82c3ce11c

Answer (score 0):

```
class _ComentCardState extends State<ComentCard> {
  bool childcomment = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
        child: CommentTreeWidget<Comment, Comment?>(
          Comment(
              avatar: 'null',
              userName: widget.snap['name'],
              content: '${widget.snap['text']} '),
          [
            Comment(avatar: 'null', userName: 'null', content: 'null'),
          ],
          treeThemeData: childcomment
              ? TreeThemeData(lineColor: Colors.green[500]!, lineWidth: 3)
              : TreeThemeData(lineColor: Colors.green[500]!, lineWidth: 3),
          avatarRoot: (context, data) => PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromRadius(18),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 18,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(widget.snap['profilePic'].toString()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          avatarChild: (context, data) => const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromRadius(12),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/assets/homescreen.png'),
            ),
          ),
          contentChild: (context, data) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'dangngocduc',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${data!.content}',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Text('Reply'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
          contentRoot: (context, data) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.snap['name'],
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${data.content}',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Text('Like'),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 24,
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: Text('Reply')),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.favorite_border,
                            size: 16,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?